# Garry's Mod - Missing Map map/<mapname>

Tags: garrys-mod

Trying to play Trouble in Terrorist Town. Every time I join a server, the progress bar goes real quick through all the files, and I get "Missing map map/<mapname>". I tried downloading the map manually and placing it in the maps folder, but that still does not work, because none of the other models/LUA scripts get downloaded either.

This issue does not happen in other sourcemod games (eg. TF2), only Garry's Mod. Before a few updates ago, it used to work on on this same computer, with the same Internet connection.

**What can I do to resolve this?**

Comment: I'm haveing the exact same problem and so is both of my friends with gmod

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Posting this question/answer here, since the solution doesn't appear to exist anywhere else *(outside of my own [steam forums post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2939915))*:

Apparently Garry's Mod uses Internet Explorer somehow for its "FastDL" downloading.  **If Internet Explorer can't connect to the internet for whatever reason, then Garry's Mod won't download anything.**

In my case, IE was set to offline-mode.  Setting it to online fixed the issue.

---

Other things you can try:

- Make sure `Options --> Multiplayer --> Download Custom Content` is set to `Allow All Custom Files From Server`
- Try adding the following lines to the bottom of your garry's mod config file, located at `Steam\steamapps\<username>\garrysmod\garrysmod\cfg\config.cfg`:

  ```
  cl_allowdownload 1
  cl_downloadfilter all
  download_debug 0
  sv_downloadurl ""
  ```
- Verify the integrity of the game files.  Within Steam:  `Library --> Garry's Mod --> Right Click --> Properties --> Local Files --> "Verify Integrity of Game Cache"`
- Try disabling your firewall/antivirus, or possibly other non-essential programs/services running.
- Try deleting your maps, lua, addons, and cache folders in the `garrysmod` folder, located at `Steam\steamapps\<username>\garrysmod\garrysmod`.  Then verify your cache again.
- As a last resort, uninstall Garry's Mod completely and delete the `garrysmod` folder *(which you'll have to do by hand, because there will be leftover files)*, then reinstall.

Answer (score -2):

This is due to addon confliction. I recommend disabling all of them to play the server I'm afraid.